# Where are my projects I made in the Elastic Beanstalk CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've created an application using the Elastic Beanstalk website interface and it appears on the homepage when I click for the Elastic Beanstalk service under 'All Applications'. I've also made an application using the Elastic Beanstalk CLI (eb init, eb create, etc.) and by logging in with an access key made with the IAM.

I can't find the application I made through the CLI in the homepage of the Elastic Beanstalk page like I would if I made the application through the website interface. Is there anyway I can view the information of my application made through the CLI on the website or is everything done through the CLI now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're looking in the right region. Our applications are all deployed in `us-east-1` aka `N. Virginia`, but several times I've seen the web console default to `us-west-1` aka `Oregon`. There's a dropdown in the upper-right corner of the web console - make sure it's set to the same region as where you deployed your application.

Answer (score 0):

when you try to look for the status of your CLI application using **eb status**, does it say status is **ready** ?

If so, the application should be available through GUI as well.

Comment: after running eb status, the applications status is ready and health is green, but still doesn't show up on the GUI. Does it have something to do with the access key I've set up through the IAM?